# Common ground between ATTiny and 24 V motor, and between ATTiny and 12 V logic circuit, without connecting 24 V motor and 12 V logic grounds

Tags: motor, ground, attiny

I have a coin hopper which has a 12 V logic circuit and a 24 V motor. It also has 2 brass plates which sense the amount of coins in the unit, one plate has high voltage, and second has low. These plates are connected to the 12 V logic.

I have an ATTiny85 which controls the 24 V motor via a BJT transistor which controls a MOSFET, which requires the motor and ATTiny to have a common ground afaik.

The problem occurs when I want to read the voltage level from the 2 brass plates. For this, I believe the ATTiny would need to have a common ground with the 12 V logic, but when common ground is established between the motor and logic, or in this case, motor, logic, and ATTiny, the motor suddenly is energized. I'm not sure why this is happening. In the datasheet, it says the motor and logic grounds are isolated in the unit.

What can I do to measure the voltage level with my ATTiny and be able to control the MOSFET, without allowing both the motor and 12 V logic circuit's grounds to be connected?

Comment: i think that you misunderstand how the brass plates work

Comment: `which requires the motor and ATTiny to have a common ground afaik` ... that is not usually true

Comment: @Bacon Your accepted answer (opto coupler) MAY work but I think probably won't. | Is the voltage to be measured Analog and variable or just on/off?. If just on/off then an optical connection from the Tiny to the on/off sensor should work. || ...

Comment: ... If you need Analog voltage measurement , then you need to understand the relationship (if any) of the two supplies (a volt-meter will help) and you may find that you need to change the uC supply source to the 12V supply and use an opto as suggested. Whether this works will depend on what else is connected to the uC. | A "surefire" solution is to add an extra ATTiny powered by the 12V rail, use it to measure coin hopper voltage and then transfer the data digitaly via an eg optocoupler. Not hard. Just annoying.

Comment: VITAL: Is the "voltage" just on/off or high/low or is it analog & variable?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It is just on/off, the voltage level does not seem to vary, so an optical connection as a signal to an ATTiny would also work.

Comment: @Bacon For just on/off then an optocoupler from coin unit to processor solves your problem. | One from processor to drive transistor probably doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an optocoupler instead of a BJT, you can avoid having a common ground between the motor and the other two blocks.  This requires more current than driving the base of a BJT, but it sounds like you're in a line-powered environment there.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work fine.

Comment: I feel like an idiot listening to the conversation of two geniuses here... The question is a bewildering mess of words and yet you somehow managed to give correct answer that OP understood?!

Comment: @Maple A risk is hearing a person think they understand the question and the OP thinking they understand the answer and thinking your comprehension lacks. It may. But, it may not. What the OP said is that when I have system A controller driving motor A and system B driving a coin hopper, when I join the A & B gounds it goes wrong. The given solution was to add an optical link twixt system A controller and driver and thus (he says) allow connections of the A & B system grounds as the A controller and A motor are now separated.  || DRAW A DIAGRAM when it gets hard like this. ...

Comment: ... HOWEVER:  In fact - there is no certainty that this will work as A controller and A motor must originally have shared the same grounds for signal flow and so have the same power supply negative common. Now the driver opto isolation MAY do some good BUT the motor and A controller still MUST have the same psu ground so deep-ending on what the problem was it may be just as bad.

Comment: @Maple Haha yes you are correct, question is quite a mess. I try not to ask questions on here too much but instead put things off until I actually understand what's going on, which I clearly don't really. I will make some edits soon.

Comment: I offered the safest idea I could think of.  It occurred to me that connecting the motor ground to the hopper ground might be how you're supposed to start the motor, but without schematics to go from I couldn't be sure there wouldn't be repercussions.

Comment: that was my point. without schematics all the answers and comments here are just wild guesses, useless for OP and waste of time for the others